# if statement not working within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am a beginner. I am doing an iterative calculation in python like

```
for i in range(30):
    if i<10:
       p = 1
    if 10<=i<20:
       p = 2
    else:
       p = 3
```

however, when I run the code, for the if i<10 case, I am getting p=3 which is the else case. I get correct p = 2 in second case. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Follow your code line by line, there is a tiny mistake that ends up running more than one of the choices for numbers below 10.

Comment: Try `if 10<=i<20`

Comment: I corrected it. the issue was not because of less or equal to. The answer by @Jason worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you code, the first `if` and the `else` statement will both run when `i < 10`. Maybe you should change your second `if` to `elif`:

```
for i in range(30):
   if i<10:
      p = 1
   elif 10<=i<20:
      p = 2
   else:
      p = 3
```